# Caesar decoder in ARM Assembly

Tags: c, string, gcc, assembly, arm

As it said in the title, my objective is to write a program in C and ARM assembly that decodes a string by shifting the byte value of each character by a certain amount. The "space" character isn't shifted, instead just copied over to the resulting string. The process ends when the null-terminator is located.

Here is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void init(char * encrypt);
extern char * decrypt(char * encrypt, int shift);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char * result;
    char encrypt[] = "GSRKVEXYPEXMSRW CSY LEZI JSYRH XLI WLMJX ZEPYI";
    int i;

    init(encrypt);
    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        result = decrypt(encrypt, i);
        printf("Possible decrypt with shift %d: %s\n", i, result);
    }
}
```

Here is my ARM code (this is all in one file called decrypt.s):

```
@ init: reserves space for the decryption
    .global init
    .text
init: stmfd sp!, {v1-v6, lr}
    mov v1, a1
    bl strlen
    bl malloc
    bufferAddr: .fill 4, 1, 0
    str a1, bufferAddr
    @mov a2, v1
    @bl strcpy

    ldmfd sp!, {v1-v6, pc}

@ decrypt: performs shifting of letters to decrypt string
    .global decrypt
    .text
decrypt: stmfd sp!, {v1-v6, lr}
    mov v1, a1 @ v1 is the pointer to encrypt (string)
    ldr v2, =bufferAddr @ v2 is the pointer to result (string)

    loop:
        ldrb v3, [v1], #1 @ v3 is the current char (8-bit number)

        cmp v3, #0
        streqb v3, [v2], #1
        beq endLabel

        cmp v3, #32 @ check if v3 == "space"
        streqb v3, [v2], #1 @ if true, store space in result, increment
        beq loop @ if true, proceed to next char

        sub v3, v3, a2 @ shift v3 by shift-value
        cmp v3, #65 @ check if v3 >= 65 (A)
        strgeb v3, [v2], #1 @ if true, store char in result, increment
        bge loop

        @ if less than A
        add v3, v3, #26 @ add 26, wrap between A-Z
        strb v3, [v2], #1 @ if true, store char in result, increment
        b loop
    endLabel:

    ldr a1, =bufferAddr

    ldmfd sp!, {v1-v6, pc}
.end
```

The problem is, it only goes through the loop once, then it gets stuck. Sometimes it prints an error along the lines of "sim: unknown SWI..." or "unknown v6 isbn...". Or worst of all, it just prints nothing (infinite loop?)

I'm not sure what the problem is, my logic seems to make sense.
I read the next byte:

- If it's null-terminator, I put it in the resulting string as well, and end the loop.
- If it's space, I put the space in the resulting string, and continue the loop.
- If it's >= 65 (which it SHOULD be, unless Space/null-terminator), I subtract the shift-value. If the resulting value is >= 65, I put it in the resulting string. If it's < 65, I add 26, then put it in the resulting string, therefore successfully wrapping to the capital letters of the alphabet.
- There is (should be) no other case.

Yet I still get errors, or possibly an infinite loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, how do I ensure that one "function/label" doesn't fall into another? Upon calling ldmfd, does it automatically return to the previous function location?

Comment: The best idea is always this: single-step through the assembly code in a debugger. Another trick is to build the code, then disassemble it again to see if it really looks like what it was supposed to be. For starters, consider the `bl malloc` call in `init` - when that returns, what do you think happens next?

Comment: No, it doesn't return. How would it know to do that? You need to tell it to return. Also it doesn't "fall" into another label. Labels are just that, labels. They're nothing more than line numbers or memory locations would be.

Comment: Are you seriously trying to use self-modifying code, or do you just not know what your `bufferAddr:` in the `.text`-section will do?

Comment: @Notlikethat Maybe I'm misinformed, but when malloc returns doesn't a1 equal the pointer to the memory location created? Then, I allocate bufferAddr (4 bytes), and put the pointer returned from malloc into bufferAddr. Is that not what's happening?

Comment: @EOF I honestly don't know what `.text` does, I saw it in the example "function" provided by my instructor. I just assumed it was required. Now I feel foolish for not asking :( As for the `bufferAddr`, my intention was to create an integer in ARM, as told to do so by my instructor, and use it to hold the address for the decrypt-buffer.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen So then I have to use `b lr` or 'bx lr' to have the label return to the original location when it was called. BTW, I read about the 'bx' online, but I couldn't find additional info on what the 'x' does. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Yes, you have to use `bx lr` to return. `b` branches somewhere, `bx` returns from a subroutine jumped to with `bl`

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thank you, I have added `bx lr` after the `ldmfd` for both labels.

Comment: I'd recommend writing the whole program in C and looking at the compiler-generated assembly. Whatever you were attempting to do in `init()`, I'm pretty sure it's unsalvageable.

Comment: Also as EOF hinted, the `bufferAddr` label should be somewhere else. Now it is in the middle of the code, so the CPU will actually execute that as code. You should put it in a `.data` segment. Assembly is very different from C. Everything is done exactly in order, variables need to be in their own place.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen The `ldmfd sp!, {v1-v6, pc}` instruction makes the `bx lr` instruction following it unnecessary. It's never executed because PC is loaded with the LR value previously saved on the stack.

Comment: @Dave "Then, I allocate bufferAddr (4 bytes)" - sounds like the next step is to study your assembler documentation and get your head round the significant difference between directives and instructions. Hint: when `malloc` returns, execution continues from the address following the `bl` instruction, which is some space set aside for data _at compilation time_; processor tries to interpret that as an instruction; all hell may or may not break loose. As for later, when it looks like you might start overwriting the rest of the code, well, as I said: debugger.

Comment: Why do you use `malloc` at all?  Your C `main` doesn't ever free anything.  **It would be better to just pass two pointers to `decrypt`: a dst and a src.**  Then the caller can reuse the same buffer or not.  I don't see any calls to `init` in your code, so even if `init` wasn't broken, it would segfault.  Returning a pointer to an internal buffer is a terrible way to design a function API, and one that C has had to replace with re-entrant versions of functions like [`asctime_r(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asctime_r.3.html).

Comment: @PeterCordes You're right, but unfortunately I have no choice. I am only permitted to edit the assembly code. The call to `init` is right before the for loop, btw.

Comment: @Notlikethat In that case I'll try to find and set up a debugger. Thanks for your help

Comment: Oh, IDK why ctrl-f or my brain was missing it before.  But note that `main` doesn't ever call `free(3)`, so `init()` can be a no-op and your asm routine can just return a pointer to a large static buffer.  Although I'm guessing part of the point of the exercise is to make you write code that passes the return value of `strlen` as a size to `malloc`, and store that pointer somewhere.  (e.g. in static storage).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str a1, bufferAddr` stores the value from the register at the memory location pointed to by `bufferAddr`. Since this is in the middle of the `init` function it works first time only.

However `ldr v2, =bufferAddr` loads the value of `bufferAddr`, this results in in the result overwriting `decrypt`.

You should use `ldr v2, bufferAddr`.

Comment: After fixing the bufferAddr storing, I was still having errors. I got rid of the equals sign in front of bufferAddr, and everything just worked. Thanks a lot everyone!